# How do I prove this Taylor Series Problem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $p\in \mathbb{R}$, and let $f(x) = (1 + x)^p$ for $-1 < x < +\infty$. Show that the Taylor series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(0) x^{k}}{k!}$ converges to $f(x)$ in the interval $-1 < x < 1$.

I have learned a littler bit of Taylor Series in my engineering courses but have not learned these proof type questions before. Can someone please help? This is my first attempt at learning analysis.

Answer (score 2):

We need to use Cauchy's form of remainder in Taylor's theorem :

> **Taylor's Theorem with Cauchy's Remainder**: If the $n$-th derivative $f^{(n)}(x) $ exists in an open interval $I$ containing point $a$ then for all values of $h$ such that $a+h\in I$ we have a corresponding number $\theta\in(0,1)$ such that $$f(a+h) =f(a) +hf'(a) +\frac{h^{2}}{2!}f''(a)+\dots+\frac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(a)+R_{n}$$ where $$R_{n} =\frac{(1-\theta)^{n-1}f^{(n)}(a+\theta h) h^{n} } {(n-1)!} $$

For the current question let $f(x) = (1+x)^{p},a=0,h=x$ and note that $$f^{(n)} (x) =p(p-1)\dots(p-n+1)(1+x)^{p-n}$$ Then we have via above mentioned theorem $$(1+x)^{p}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{p}{k}x^{k}+R_{n}\tag{1}$$ where $$R_{n} =\frac{p(p-1)\dots(p-n+1)} {(n-1)!}\cdot\frac{(1-\theta)^{n-1}x^{n}}{(1+\theta  x) ^{n-p}} \tag{2}$$ If $p$ is a positive integer then $R_{p+1}=0$ so that the series is finite with sum $(1+x)^{p}$ (this is the usual binomial theorem for positive integer index $p$). If $p$ is not a positive integer then we need to analyze the expression $R_{n} $ a bit more carefully.

If $|x|<1$ then $0<(1-\theta)/(1+\theta x) <1$ and $(1+\theta x)^{p-1}$ is less than $(1+|x|)^{p-1}$ if $m>1$ and less than $(1-|x|)^{p-1}$ if $p<1$. Therefore $$|R_{n} |<|p|(1\pm|x|)^{p-1}\left|\binom {p-1}{n-1}\right||x|^{n}\tag{3}$$ where the sign $+$ or $-$ is chosen according as $p>1$ or $p<1$.

It can be easily proved (via ratio test) that the RHS of the above inequality tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ provided that $|x|<1$. Thus $R_{n} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ and therefore from equation $(1)$ it follows that the series in question converges to sum $(1+x)^{p}$ for $|x|<1$. Things are a bit tricky when $x=\pm 1$. More details are available in my blog posts [here](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part1.html) and [here](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part-2.html).

Comment: Well done +1 ...

Answer (score 1):

Recall  *Taylor-Young* formula asserts that
$$ (1+x)^p=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}(0) x^{k}}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{p(p-1)\dotsm(p-k+1)}{k!}x^{k}+R_n(x) $$
where  $\quad R_n(x)= o(x^n)$. There results $R_n(x)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ if $\,|\,x\,|<1$.

Comment: That will show that the series _converges_ for $|x|<1$, but the question was to prove that it converges to $(1+x)^p$.

Comment: @Professor Vector: I should have carefully read the whole question. Thanks for pointing it! I'll change my answer in a moment.

Comment: @Bernard How long does a moment last to you? :-)

Comment: Time to hunt the Snark ;o)